# Problem in using FrameTicks option in DateListPlot command

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

everyone.

I have prepared a code in which a file of data to be called and its data will be used to make a plot. I wanted to divide the x axis, as I needed but the output is not what I need. I want to divide the x axis into 12 or 24 equal intervals. It's kind of if you help me. In the following, you can see the code and its output

Best regards.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
P = Abs[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/VqZFMsSf", "List"]];
rec = Table[i, {i, 1, Length[P]}];
data = Transpose@{rec, P};
{maxn, minn} = {MaximalBy[#, Last], MinimalBy[#, Last]} &@data;

p1 = DateListPlot[{data, Labeled[maxn, "{{95,5,4},234.6}", {Right}]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize -> Medium, Red, Point@maxn}, 
Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24}, None}}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Day", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(total\)]\)"}]
Export["103MT880823-day.pdf", p1];
Print["The maximum is = ", Max[P]];
Print["The Minimum is = ", Min[P]];
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkFOS.jpg)

Comment: Where is `P-5-4-95.dat`, so that other people can try things out?

Comment: I don't know how  I can upload its file. By the way, here is its data

-181
-182.9
-173.4
-165.1
-155
-152.7
-149.8
-146.5
-146.4
-145.8
-140.7
-134.6
-121.9
-114.1
-108.5
-110.2
-116
-116.6
-123.4
-136.9
-148.8
-165.1
-175.2
-179.7
-175.8
-178.4
-180.4
-167.2
-180.6
-187.5
-200.9
-194.7
-190.3
-202.5
-200.8
-211.7
-227.6
-234.6
-233.4
-216
-217.3
-202.7
-214.5
-211.8
-213.6
-209.3
-197.8
-194.8

Comment: I would suggest pasting the contents of the *.dat file into [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), and post the link here.

Comment: Is there any option to upload a file there?

Comment: No; open the *.dat file in a text editor, copy the contents, and then paste it there.

Comment: Thanks, Here is the link

https://pastebin.com/VqZFMsSf

Comment: Try this `FrameTicks` setting instead: `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{#, IntegerString[#/2]} & /@ Range[0, 48, 4], None}}`.

Comment: Thanks, dear. It worked out